# Dynamically Navigating an IVR with Twilio

Tags: python, twilio

I'm considering traversing an (unknown) IVR using twilio. One of the considerations I have is whether Twilio is able to dial input (say, press 1) during the call, without presetting before execution. So I would dial a number, then decide the input for the call somehow, and dial this into the current call. How would I use twilio to dial this into the current call?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That's a bit of a difficult one. I'm not sure Twilio is currently the best platform to navigate an unknown IVR, however I have seen it done (at a hackathon, no less), so don't rule it out.

In order to send input to an IVR you can use the [`<Play>` TwiML verb with the `digits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits). Were you to know the IVR ahead of time you could use the [`SendDigits` parameter when making the call with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).

To automatically navigate the IVR, you'd need to string together responses using `<Play>` to send the right digit and [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) to take input from the IVR, transcribe it and decide, somehow, what to do next.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi phil, thanks, this looks good! The issue now is that we need to figure out when we've reached a human speaker, and we can't use this approach for that (it's much too slow). Would you know anything about this?